# Как вычислить значение ключа словаря из значений других ключей этого же словаря?

Tags: python, словари, dict

Как тут в k0 получить сумму k1 и k2?

```
raznoe = {
    #коэффициент относительной аварийности (количество дорожно-транспортных происшествий в расчете на 1 млн автомобиле-километров)
    'k0': raznoe['k1']+raznoe['k2'], #автомагистраль
    'k1': 0.25, #многополосная дорога с разделительной полосой
    'k2': 0.29, #многополосная дорога без разделительной полосы
    'k3': 0.42, #двухполосная дорога и прочие категории дорог

    'calc_k4': None, #Ставка дисконтирования
    'calc_k5': None, #количество торговых дней в квартале, предшествующем кварталу проведения оценки, в течение которых осуществлялись торги с использованием системы электронных торгов публичного акционерного общества «Московская биржа ММВБ-РТС»
    'k6': 1, #Индекс дня

}
```

Понятное дело, что это можно сделать после формирования словаря, просто его дополнив потом, но может можно сделать как то на лету, во время первичного формирования словаря? Возможно для этого есть что то типо this?

Comment: У вас имя объекта еще не существует полноценно на момент, как вы пытаетесь к нему обратиться. Рекомендую всё же включить в вопрос пояснение цели, которую вы хотите этим достичь, а также указать, откуда в словарь попадают `k1` и `k2`.

Comment: В данном контексте ваши вопросы не имеют смысла, пусть это будет просто исследованием возможностей языка, если это для вас так важно.

Comment: Это для вас должно быть важно. Все возможности языка нацелены на достижение конкретного результата. Под него и надо подбирать путь достижения. Я на этом остановлюсь с данным вопросом.

Comment: В целом я пришёл к выводу, что это не возможно в контексте словаря. Только классом если делать. Вопрос снят.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно сделать ленивое вычисление значений используя вспомогательную функцию:

```
class ThisAccessor:
    def __init__(self, accessor):
        self.accessor = accessor
    
    def __call__(self, this):
        return self.accessor(this)

def dict_calc(d):                             
    return {k:v(d) if isinstance(v, ThisAccessor) else v for k, v in d.items()}
       
raznoe = dict_calc({
    'k0': ThisAccessor(lambda this: this['k1']+this['k2']),
    'k1': 0.25, 
    'k2': 0.29, 
})
```

Если в словаре будут только значения и функций не будет, то можно обойтись без `ThisAccessor`:

```
def dict_calc(d):                             
    return {k:v(d) if callable(v) else v for k, v in d.items()}
       
raznoe = dict_calc({
    'k0': lambda this: this['k1']+this['k2'],
    'k1': 0.25, 
    'k2': 0.29, 
})
```